# How to wait for DropBox download synchronization to be done?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, chdropboxsync

iI need to ensure that DropBox cache (local files) is up to date with remote files stored on the Dropbox server. (My app needs to wait for local files being completely up to date, before reading them)

I have searched the core api for clues on how to do that, checked the /delta api, but this does not seems related to want I need to achieve. **I can only use HTTP to access dropbox apis.**

So, how to detect that dropbox is still synchronizing data (downstream), or has finished its download?

Any idea is welcome, preferably using the dropbox core api

(Please note that using a CRC of all files is not possible because thousands of files are stored and computing a CRC on this complexe files structure is not acceptable for my app performances)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to detect whether a local file system is up-to-date with respect to the data server-side in Dropbox?

Comment: So you are not _implementing_ the whole local cache thing yourself, but are using the official dropbox client for your platform – and you want to get the info when _that_ is done updating all files? I doubt this is possible.

Comment: @CBroe: please see my comment to smarx answer: it seems possible, with the sync api, but it is not available for ms windows

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does not have an API that gives you information about which client apps have downloaded which files, so there's no way to do what you ask.

Comment: I've seen that the sync api is able to do so. My app is a desktop app, I only need to check for local cache status. The problem is that the sync api is not available for ms windows, so looking for another way...

Comment: The Sync API is kind of a misnomer... it's just an SDK built on top of the Core API. It's a way for your app to download the files itself. It in no way communicates with the desktop client.